# How to loop through dataframes and delete empty columns (in R)?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I want to delete empty columns for multiple dataframes using for loop or lapply.

My dataframes always start with "test.xxx".

If I do it one by one as below, it works.

```
test.acc_consoles2 <- Filter(function(x)!all(is.na(x) || is.null(x) || x == "" || x == 0), test.acc_consoles2)
```

However, if I use for loop or lapply, it doesn't work. I tried the following code already.

```
for(i in lst) {
  i <- Filter(function(x)!all(is.na(x) || is.null(x) || x == "" || x == 0),x=i)
}
```

I want to have clean dataframes with no empty columns. Since there are 189 dataframes, I would like to use lapply or for loop.

Comment: `output <- lapply(lst, function(df) 
  Filter(function(x)!all(is.na(x) || is.null(x) || x == "" || x == 0),df))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `lapply` and filter the columns from each dataframe in the list

```
output <- lapply(lst, function(df) 
     Filter(function(x)!all(is.na(x) || is.null(x) || x == "" || x == 0),df))
```